# Common emitter question

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, homework

Consider the common-emitter (CE) amplifier below:

Given: VCC = 10 V, RC = 3 kΩ, RBB = 100 kΩ, β = 100, VT = 25 mV, VBIAS = 3 V, VBE (ON) = 0.7 V, r0 = ∞.

DC analysis: Prove that transistor Q1 is operating in Forward Active Region (BE forward-active, CB reverse-biased).

AC analysis: Calculate gm, rπ, draw the small signal model for the transistor and the whole circuit, then prove that voltage gain Vout/Vin = -2.98 V/V.

For the first part, I'm not sure how to solve it. As for the second part, I can't find the right equation for gm and r.

Should I use gm=ic/vbe, if yes, how do I find Ic? Or Ic/VT? In both cases I'm not sure how to find Ic.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use VBIAS and VBE(on) to calculate the voltage across RBB, and with that, the current flowing into the transistor's base. Using beta, you can find the collector current, and then continue from there.

Don't forget that Rb (the small-signal input impedance of the transistor's base) forms a voltage divider with RBB when you want to calculate the circuit's gain.

Answer (score -1):

To start with, figure out the DC state. First, find out what the maximum possible collector current is. That's when the transistor is saturated, with \$V_{CE} \approx 0\$, implying maximum voltage across \$R_C\$.

$$ I_{C(SAT)} = \frac{V_{CC}}{R_C} = \frac{10V}{3k\Omega} = 3.33mA $$

Then determine the minimum DC base current that is required to create that condition of saturation.

$$ I_{B(SAT)} = \frac{I_{C(SAT)}}{\beta} = \frac{3.3mA}{100} = 33.3\mu A $$

If we now calculate the *actual* DC base current flowing, then we can establish if the transistor is saturated or not:

$$ I_B = \frac{V_{RBB}}{R_{BB}} = \frac{V_{IN(DC)}-V_{BE(ON)}}{R_{BB}} = \frac{3-0.7}{100k\Omega} = 23\mu A $$

That's clearly less than \$I_{B(SAT)}\$, so this transistor is working in its active region. What is the *actual* DC collector current flowing?

$$ I_C = \beta I_B = 100 \times 23\mu A = 2.3mA $$

With \$I_C\$ known, now you can get on with the AC part, starting with transconductance:

$$ g_m = \frac{I_C}{V_T} $$

Comment: Please don't hand out solutions to homework questions.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson It's only the find Ic part, and I stopped there. I want numbers to show maxima. It's a fine line, I admit, but I did what I felt was necessary for OP to "get it". Feel how you feel, but the downvote wasn't called for.